# Grails g:link - include app name in resulting anchor href attribute

Tags: grails, gsp

This GSP:

```
<g:link controller="book" action="show" id="5">Example</g:link>
```

results in this HTML:

```
<a href="/book/show/5">Example</a>
```

This is relative to the HTTP host. If your site is running at http://localhost:8080 that's fine.

During development, an app will more commonly be running at http://localhost:8080/appName.

In such cases, the above link will not work - it will result in an absolute URL of http://localhost:8080/book/show/5 instead of the required http://localhost:8080/appName/book/show/5

What changes are required of the above GSP  for the app name to be present in the resulting anchor's href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration setting `grails.app.context` should be equal to the context where you want your application deployed.  If it's not set, as in the default configuration, it defaults to your application name, like `http://localhost:8080/appName`.  If you want to deploy your app in the root context (e.g. `http://locahost:8080/`), add this to your `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```

If the context is properly set, the URLs generated by `g:link` tags will include the context before the controller name.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the `meta` tag is very useful for getting information in GSP files.

For example, if you want your application name, you can get it like this:

```
<g:meta name="app.name"/>
```

You can get any property in your `application.properties` file like that.

And if you, like me, need to concatenate it to another value, here is my example. Remember that any tag can be used as a method without the `g:` namespace. For example:

```
<g:set var="help" value="http://localhost:8080/${meta(name:"app.name")}/help" />
```

Grails documentation about this is a little poor, but it is [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/meta.html).

Answer (score 1):

For me the single best reason to use `<g:link>` is that it adds the context if there is one, or omits it if you're running at http://localhost:8080 or in prod at http://mycoolsite.com - it's trivial to just concatenate the parts together yourself otherwise.

The same goes for using `g:resource` with css, javascript, etc. - it lets you have one GSP that works regardless of what the context is (e.g. 'appName'), since it's resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what grails.serverURL is for. You defined this config variable in the Config.groovy, check the [configuration documentation for Grails](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

createLink tag includes your appname / context parameter automatically in the link.

Here is [reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Tags/createLink.html) doc for it.